# ¿Cómo puedo reiniciar una imagen en javascript?

Tags: javascript

estoy empezando en javascript y en mi primer proyecto estoy haciendo un editor de imagenes , en el cual, hice un input="range" para editar el grosor del borde dependiendo de si es mayor o menor el valor del input range, al hacer el borde más y más grande, funciona perfectamente,pero al hacerlo pequeño , aparece el más grande que se haya selecionado.Creo que esto es porque no se reinicia la imagen y el nuevo borde se pone por debajo del anterior.Por ello pregunto,¿como puedo reiniciar una imagen utilizando javascript?.
Este es el codigo, por si desean verlo:https://codepen.io/jlopy/pen/qBmqbvw
PD:(la imagen se inserta en un canvas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para reiniciar la variable global debes poner al final de la funcion lo siguiente:
borderimg=null;
borderimg=new SimpleImage(file);
de esta manera se reiniciara la variable global  de la imagen y , por tanto , la imagen.
Un saludo y pasalo bien programando.

Comment: Gracias , has solucionado mi problema, muchisimas gracias giorgio.